# Given a list of strings, find the shortest unique substring of each string that doesn't occur in the other strings

Tags: python, string, algorithm, dynamic-programming

The problem statement is:

> Given a list of strings, find the *shortest* unique substring of each string such that the substring does not occur in any of the other strings.

For example:

```
Input: ["cheapair", "cheapoair", "peloton", "pelican"]
Output:
"cheapair": "pa"  // every other 1-2 length substring overlaps with cheapoair
"cheapoair": "po" // "oa" would also be acceptable
"pelican": "ca"   // "li", "ic", or "an" would also be acceptable
"peloton": "t"    // this single letter doesn't occur in any other string
```

I think this is solved with dynamic programming, but honestly, I have no idea how to do this other than brute force: Storing all substrings for each word and checking that they don't exist in any of the other ones, which is a terrible idea.

Comment: Is there any issue with this approach? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18479878

Comment: I think this is a typical problem for the sliding window approach.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Came across this problem for interview prep. Suffix arrays, suffix trees, I've never heard of (I come from a math background, not CS), and I've been doing leetcode problems for some time now. I was hoping someone would suggest a solution using more common data structures.

Comment: What are correct results for Riccardo's example input `["abab", "ba"]`?

Comment: And since it talks about "the" substring (with the property) of each string, and there are no instructions for what to do if a string doesn't have one, are we guaranteed that each string does have at least one?

Comment: @KellyBundy You raise a good point. I wonder if the solution would be the empty string then, but in terms of set theory, the empty set is part of every subset, so it wouldn't be unique to "ba". Perhaps that's not a "valid" test case as in that won't ever happen.

Answer (score 4):

Building all substrings to find those that appear in two (or more) strings. Then for each string, print a shortest substring that doesn't appear in two (or more). Maybe not the best (depends on your data and what you consider "best"), but works and is simple.

```
strings = ["cheapair", "cheapoair", "peloton", "pelican"]

def substrings(s):
    n = len(s)
    return {s[i:i+k]
            for k in range(1, n+1)
            for i in range(n-k+1)}

one = set()
two = set()
for s in strings:
    subs = substrings(s)
    two |= one & subs
    one |= subs

for s in strings:
    subs = substrings(s)
    uniq = subs - two
    print(s, min(uniq, key=len))
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZBNjsIwDIX3OYXVxSgRZYHYIKSeBLEojAGr4IQkFULDnL3EafiRWOGVn/3l@SnuGg@W5wvnhyFET7wP0MCq2h6wdS35qoaxt0U4PNpoubS0bblaK/WLOwj9pjjoYJYKUnHyOiInnaXH2HuGv7CiJU26dR4@amc9dEAMvuU96lkNPJmZD4ReCE@7RPwrZRnToYBRGxUv9tkLH4QvucZQklOQ97h5IU9vDYjbT17nqcjbiKtvHXumc1nAVPzz1CUm6lDDiVgLUkOH1yZ9lDHDcAc)):

```
cheapair pa
cheapoair oa
peloton t
pelican an
```

**Preliminary** [benchmark](https://tio.run/##fVXbbuIwEH3nK7yquk0ERZS@rCLxBVt1PyCKkAkGrDpOajvNst1@Ozszzs1N2TzBXM9czrg6u1OpH39U5nI5mLJgThZCOiaLqjSO7cWB18ptUWoYt6Q2M7LMS6VE7mSp7SfzvczdAv681sKbWmekPnZWFfxxfKcEBuSqOvGdcLMZOLOfQqnzOmpKs7dxMmPwodjWOx/CRp0YPyNcbTR7t6lM5FzprNd036E0TDKpmeH6KCIlNAS4V3r@EH@QMWViG2aFa7OSmCv5JkBMomVeVufIK5QG6cq7niSWgJYDJNDPN@yh/19q0UaPe5lryokMK0Qc7zYJq6USLJZAWD5m49LsgoxRSwGW0onCRqMWdfn@bgjKd7ILtCgGbSDvcyppXUQlfoopD6zW8pUl3tOmNmP3mCmZzOAshdojVHSYaCn40oiifBNQrl@DZ5m/BEtww56gOTC@ozux8sAK/pv60SqfQanrYgc7CkpyJA2YgQ8o4QcNv/H9bPp@xsxH@BU9@2EAEi41NL/bDGrBaDXQH6bc79TDok0DO5X00Z6G0d6wg9R7KFSB331@4obnDpAOY0bQguenoaRuJZyhpRimDlEG@YhuEaxTHMxvqDEJGj6q9VOmZV3tuRPRO/gmnhEdsb4iUhPPH4BKccw@4knRPYo1OQVNTa4CaTcLnL4B96arFHYgbdZZh7kXZTEbdV6XDRQiMCjXZ8aN0HcOEbmTYEdV7riiAU87F0JOkyy5BhrXukaWp3YgzoAHc1sAQmnH4LPsah/ABTvsI8fXKNUs2twTfQi@Y1czJGkThHYx28BtC7PtjOAvnpS6NAWw9Y8ANwtr13GzvcIpkQQOEpx4sY@G7Y6/2ApvORAAO@b9utjZbHaodY5r7h@FBV0FD8WJnpNJcMZdXSkxZqv4XcEbheehR09h01XWmg2sRgUiIYPxK4OIJiECd1pMawW8bp35ps3dh98O9HkczfQ/mel4r7AsfHWjsI/0vI6RLNgqtKB3Nrq7Xa5xA@/YLYvaQHiqV@CA3svtVvNCbLdwe7GF/YPc9TTF5zVjcwYskNnXTyqMazSTy@Uf) with a modified version that proceeds by length like Nick's does. Take this with some bags of salt: 1) The question has unclear issues (I asked under the question now). 2) The solutions yield *all* valid substrings instead of just one. 3) I modified Nick's a little to make it work here (nothing that should influence its speed). 4) It's a worst case input, where each string needs the maximum length, i.e., has no unique substring other than itself.

```
0.19 s  Kelly2
1.34 s  Nick
0.19 s  Kelly2
1.35 s  Nick
0.19 s  Kelly2
1.34 s  Nick
```

Comment: What is the time complexity here?

Comment: Also, what's the space complexity?

Comment: I'm sure you guys can figure it out if you want. 10:30 am, I'm finally going to sleep. Didn't write this for efficiency. Easily good enough for the example input. In an interview, this could be a good initial solution. And here, it could be good for testing better solutions for correctness on moderately large inputs.

Comment: Sorry for asking. But you simply answered with a solution described in the question itself (i.e., *Storing all substrings for each word and checking that they don't exist in any of the other ones*). And that solution is referred as *a terrible idea* in the question.

Comment: Also, I think the solution you proposed is wrong. Indeed, the question asks for the shortest *unique* substring, not just the shortest one.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco I interpret that differently. They said "Storing all substrings for each word". I'm storing all substrings for **all** words combined. I.e., to me it sounds like their idea is to store separate sets, one for each word, and then instead of my `uniq = subs - two`, they have a loop over those sets. Mine's faster than that by factor n, where n is the number of words.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco I **am** showing a shortest *unique* one.

Comment: In my opinion (but I might be wrong), with `strings = ["abab", "ba"]` you should return `abab --> aba`. Instead it's returning `abab --> ab`, which is not unique (you can find `ab` twice in `abab`). Also it's failing in the second iteration (`uniq` can't be empty), but that's a minor fix

Comment: @RiccardoBucco `"ab"`  isn't necessarily the answer to your example; this is something OP must clarify.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Hmm... maybe. I interpreted "unique" as a being unique to the string they're in, i.e., just that it's not in another string as well. Not an additional requirement within each string, which to me just seems like hassle without making the task more interesting.

Comment: @RiccardoBucco About "failing" when `uniq` is empty: indeed a minor fix, if necessary. I was aware of that, but the task says to find "the" unique substring, meaning there *is* one. Granted, it also means there is *exactly* one, and the examples disagree with that. But nowhere does the task specify what to do if there isn't any, so that's another indication that there won't be such an input.

Comment: Ok thanks Kelly. +1 for all the time you spent on this, answering question and comments :)

Comment: @KellyBundy thanks for all the feedback on my answer; it does show you shouldn't post late at night... :-P you should update your answer with the new version of code that you benchmarked, looks like it is a nice combination of yours with a couple of good bits from mine.

Comment: @Nick Yes, it's a nice combination of ours. Oh, I thought I had mentioned that but apparently forgot, done now. And yes, I intend to update the code in the answer, but I'll wait for answers to my clarification questions.

Comment: @KellyBundy I'll do that thing with the up arrow in anticipation :)

Comment: @AbhinavMathur I apologize for the delay! I honestly do not know what the answer to that would be. The empty string wouldn't be unique, so I think that's not a "valid" test case, even though it clearly is.